# PG version 8.10.0 is not working on Node.js v19.8.1. What should be fixed?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, pg

```
TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "string" argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer or ArrayBuffer. Received an instance of Object
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:387:5)
    at Function.byteLength (node:buffer:740:11)
    at Writer.addCString (C:\Users\anisha\tradephlo\admin-backend\node_modules\pg-protocol\dist\buffer-writer.js:42:30)
    at Object.startup (C:\Users\anisha\tradephlo\admin-backend\node_modules\pg-protocol\dist\serializer.js:10:32)
    at Connection.startup (C:\Users\anisha\tradephlo\admin-backend\node_modules\pg\lib\connection.js:128:33)
    at Connection.<anonymous> (C:\Users\anisha\tradephlo\admin-backend\node_modules\pg\lib\client.js:120:13)
    at Connection.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (C:\Users\anisha\tradephlo\admin-backend\node_modules\pg\lib\connection.js:49:12)
    at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:627:28)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:525:35) {
  code: 'ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE'
}
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting..
```

I tried the PG to version 8.2.2, which works, but the produnction does not.

Comment: PostgreSQL version 8.2? Are you 100% sure? That version is EOL for over a decade. Use something new, like version 15 or so

Comment: There has never been a PG 8.10.  And if there were, going from 8.10 to 8.2 would not be an "upgrade".

Comment: I am not using postgresql version. I am talking about pg version 8.10.0, which is not working.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.